# ¿Cómo descargar al tablet una app con código de descarga gratis, sin pasar por el play store?

Tags: android, google-play, itunes

**Explicación:**

Tengo una aplicación en el **store de Google Play**, y hemos generado 500 códigos de descarga gratis para 500 usuarios diferentes. La app es de pago normalmente. Quisiera saber cómo se podría hacer que el usuario a quien va dirigida la descarga gratis, no tenga que pasar por el paso de la inserción en Play Store del código y pudiera con ese código único para él, descargarse la app directamente en su tablet.

Quizás con una URL, o alguna herramienta se pueda obtener la descarga sin tener que introducir el código en la sección de validación del Play Store.

En resumen la idea es hacer esto mismo que permite el **Apple Store**: Al clicar el enlace de muestra de itunes la app se descarga directamente al dispositivo, *no hay que ir a poner el código en ningún lugar*.

En `itunes` hemos logrado generar una ruta que incluye el código de descarga es algo como esto (el código en negrita es inventado para poner el ejemplo):

https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=**0000000dfdf0000**

... y tenemos 500 enlaces diferentes para cada usuario, pero en *Google* no sabemos cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Creo que esta clarísima la pregunta.

Comment: Quizá ayuda esto: https://www.techmesto.com/download-android-apps-google-play-store-without-account/

Comment: Ayuda bastante @MiquelColl pero no lo suficiente. Me ha permitido darme cuenta de que faltaba información en mi pregunta, y la he editado para que se comprenda mejor.

Comment: https://play.google.com/redeem?code={CODE} Puede ser esto. Lo he encontrado aquí: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36669986/deep-linking-promotion-codes-for-paid-app-in-google-play

Comment: Tenía buena pinta tu respuesta, pero cuando lo hemos probado en un teléfono con login hecho en el play store, nos pide de introducir el código promocional de descarga y es ese paso de hecho que queremos omitir.

Comment: No entiendo que esté en espera la pregunta, creo que se entiende super bien.

Comment: En mi opinión, esta pregunta no apunta a un caso como las preguntas de SuperUser, sino a "*[herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*". Por eso, estoy votando para reabrirla.

Comment: Yo la veo válida pero creo que deberíamos hablar en meta al respeto para saber qué opina la comunidad ya que ayer en el chat había opiniones dispares.

Comment: Esta pregunta se está discutiendo en meta: [Pregunta en espera, ¿Por qué?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/961/127)

Comment: @marc ya que no quieres seguir los pasos que marca la PlayStore... porque no proporcionar vosotros mismos la descarga desde un servidor propio? Así sería super fácil comprobar los codigos promocionales....

Comment: No es que no quiera seguir los pasos, al contrario siempre es mejor hacer lo que es recomendable hacer. Pero en este caso es el cliente que no quiere que el usuario tenga que escribir un código. Si lo pongo en un servidor y sigo teniendo que poner los códigos, pues estamos igual. Y si lo que dices es poner el apk para descargar, entonces la app podría pulular después por internet de forma gratis. Es un riesgo para mi cliente.

Answer (score 5):

De [Create promo codes for your apps and in-app products in the Google Play Developer Console](http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2016/01/create-promo-codes-for-your-apps-and-in.html)

> Los usuarios pueden canjear sus codigos de descuento en las siguientes formas:
>
> - Desde Google Play, utilizando la opción de menú de **canjear**.
> - A partir de su aplicación. Que van a ser dirigidas al flujo de pago antes de dirigirse a su aplicación
> - **Al seguir un enlace que incrusta el código promocional.**
>
> Puede incrustar el código de una URL para que los usuarios no tengan
>   que escribirlo ellos mismos (por ejemplo, si va a enviar sus códigos
>   en un correo electrónico). Puede utilizar la URL:
>   `https://play.google.com/redeem?code={CODE}` (donde {CODE} es un
>   código promocional generado).

Para generar los codigos seguimos [Create promotions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495?hl=en)

> Paso 3: Configuración de una promoción en la consola de desarrollador
>
> - Vaya a su la consola de desarrollo de Google Play.
> - Seleccione su aplicación.
> - Promociones seleccione> Añadir nueva promoción.
> - Leer y aceptar las condiciones de uso.
> - Siga las instrucciones que aparecen en pantalla para nombrar a su promoción, configurar las fechas de inicio y fin, seleccionar el tipo
>     de promoción, e introduzca el número de codigos de descuento que desea
>     crear.
> - Para activar la promoción durante las fechas de inicio y de finalización que ha entrado, establecer el estado en "On".
> - Seleccione Crear.
> - Espere unos segundos y seleccione el enlace de descarga.
>
> **Sus códigos se descargarán en un archivo CSV. Para compartir con los usuarios, puede imprimir los códigos o enviar un enlace directo que
>   permite a los usuarios canjear los códigos a través de correo
>   electrónico o una notificación en su aplicación.**

Comment: Gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder. Pero todo eso ya lo tenía hecho antes de formular la pregunta. Y lo de https://play.google.com/redeem?code={CODE} me lo comentó @MiquelColl y no funciona, sigue pidiendo introducir el código para bajar la app y es justamente ese paso que queremos obviar.

Comment: @MarcLemien esta *es* la solucion. La que provee google, lo dice claramente el blogpost linkeado. Si no te funciono, quiza deberias editar esta pregunta o hacer otra, explicando lo que hiciste y los resultados que obtubiste para poder tener los elementos para ayudarte. **Hace valer la recomensa**, edita el post agregando tus ultimos intentos. Salu2

Comment: Ya se que es la buena solución, la correcta, pero no es lo que busco, aparte ya sabía hacerlo eso. (La clienta quiere que al poner ese enlace se auto-descargue en el tablet automáticamente sin tener que insertar el código de nuevo, que es lo que actualmente pasa) O sea que la solución oficial de google no sirve, porque no hace lo que hace itunes que es lo que que yo quiero hacer. Mi pregunta esta muy editada y tiene ejemplos claros de lo que quiero hacer, esta todo clarísimo.

Comment: @MarcLemien Desafortunadamente esta es la forma oficial, y parece que no hay forma de saltarse ese paso, al menos por ahora. Tal ves poner el issue en el [google/code de android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list) pueda hacer que los devs se tomen esta idea para futuros releases

Comment: Eso estaría bien.

Answer (score 0):

La única manera en la que puedes hacer que los usuarios se bajen una app sin pasar por Google Play, es que no este en Google Play.

Puedes subirla tu a una web e implementar un "formulario" de descarga, o montarla en una tienda online y "vender" la apk dando cupones de descuento, o publicarla en otra tienda (amazon por ejemplo).

Pero si te sales de estar en tiendas (sea la que sea) te sales de la posibilidad de actualizar automaticamente las apps en tus clientes.

Comment: Esta aplicación está ya en el Google Play y en iTunes en venta desde hace mucho tiempo. Ninguna de esas opciones que ofreces es factible. Solo la que itunes ya nos está proporcionando y que ya estamos usando. Lo mismo pero en Google Play Store debería ser posible. Es muy raro que no se pueda hacer, cuando Google suele ser mucho más permisivo que Apple.

Comment: Para poder instalar una app que este fuera de Google Play hay que activar en el telefono la opcion "Origenes deconocidos". Muy pocos usuarios estarán dispuestos a reducir la seguridad de su telefono para poder instalar una aplicacion.

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario. Nunca he dicho que la aplicación esté fuera de Google Play.

Comment: De momento la respuesta de @Mulflar aunque no me sirva es la única que trata de ayudarme con una solución posible. La otra respuesta solo ofrece la solución oficial que cualquiera pueda encontrar en la web oficial de google en el Developer Console Help. Por lo que de tener que otorgar la recompensa a alguien de momento solo esta puede ganar algo, pues es la que mas intenta ayudarme.

Comment: Si te sirve de algo, yo intente hacer "algo parecido" con las aplicaciones que utilizan los tecnicos de la empresa, probe opciones de beta, de "empresa", pero al final no encontre nada mas "fácil" que publicarla y ya esta.

Comment: Te he otorgado los +50 aunque la respuesta no me sirve. Es que más tarde ya no me podré conectar. El visto bueno esperaré a ver si salen más respuestas. Quizás con el tiempo alguien encuentre como obviar el paso de introducir el código. - La otra pregunta no me ayuda en nada ya que todo lo que comenta ya lo comentaba otro compañero y además ya lo sabía. Esta en google help.